# C# Nested Linq Group By

Tags: linq, group-by

**I'd like to achive this output, ONE VIEWMODEL INSTANCE for each customer**

| CUSTOMER |
| --- |
| TUI |

| DATE | PASSENGERS | VESSEL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/05/2021 | 2 | MORNING STAR |
| 01/05/2021 | 7 | CAPTAIN JOHN |
| 01/05/2021 | 10 | CAPTAIN JOHN |

| VESSEL | PASSENGERS |
| --- | --- |
| CAPTAIN JOHN | 17 |
| MORNING STAR | 2 |
| TOTAL | 19 |

**This is the model**

```
public class Reservation {
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Destination { get; set; }
    public string Customer { get; set; }
    public string Vessel { get; set; }
    public int TotalPersons { get; set; }
}
```

**This is the view model so far**

```
public class ReservationVM {
    public string Customer { get; set; }
    public List<Reservation> Reservations { get; set; }
}
```

**So far, I can only create the list with the customer and the reservations**

| CUSTOMER |
| --- |
| TUI |

| DATE | PASSENGERS | VESSEL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/05/2021 | 2 | MORNING STAR |
| 01/05/2021 | 7 | CAPTAIN JOHN |
| 01/05/2021 | 10 | CAPTAIN JOHN |

**Code**

```
public IEnumerable<ReservationVM> Get() {
   var result = dbContext.Reservations
                .Where(x => x.Date == "2021-05-01")
                .AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Customer)
                .Select(x => new ReservationVM {
                    Customer = x.Key,
                    Reservations = x.ToList()
                })
                .OrderBy(x => x.Customer);
   return result;
}
```

How could I include the part that displays the total passengers for each vessel?

| VESSEL | PASSENGERS |
| --- | --- |
| CAPTAIN JOHN | 17 |
| MORNING STAR | 2 |
| TOTAL | 19 |

Comment: Why do you a GroupBy? Does one customer have multiple reservations on a given day? and what is the name of VASSEL model, `dbContext.Vassels`?

Comment: Are all strings in `Reservation` foreign keys? Is `string Customer` the foreign key to Customer, or is it the name of the Customer? Similarly: is `string Vessel` the name of the Vessel, like `Morning Star`, or is it the foreign key to the Vessel that has a name Morning Star?

Comment: @ dovid: 1. A customer can have multiple reservations. 2. For simplicity reasons, Vessel is not a model. As you can see, it's only a property of the class "Reservation".

Comment: @ Harald Coppoolse: The "Reservation" class, in this example, doesn't have any FKs. All properties are strings. I've also updated the "ReservationVM" to simplify things. In any case, I could post the entire class if needed.

Comment: Your last table (entitled with `VESSEL, PASSANGERS`) includes three vessels, where the last vessel is called `"TOTAL"` :) I'm only half-joking here, as you should understand that implementing a representation of this table will literally have to include a vessel named `"TOTAL"`. You probably don't want that. Rather, you want a `Total` field on the `ReservationVM` level, right?

Comment: @OfirD Your assumption is correct: The `Total` field is the sum of the passengers (17+2=19), not the name of a vessel 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Total` field must be at the level of `ReservationVM` (unless you want a vessel named `Total`, which you don't). Also, you should create another class, let's call it `VesselReservationVm`. You can do something as follows:

**Classes:**

```
public class Reservation {
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Customer { get; set; }
    public string Vessel { get; set; }
    public int TotalPersons { get; set; }
}

public class ReservationVM {
    public string Customer { get; set; }
    public List<Reservation> Reservations { get; set; }
    public List<VesselReservationVM> VesselReservations { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
}
    
public class VesselReservationVM {
    public string Vessel { get; set; }
    public int Passengers { get; set; }
}
```

**Methods:**

```
public IEnumerable<ReservationVM> GetCustomersReservations() {
   var result = dbContext.Reservations
                .Where(x => x.Date == "2021-05-01")
                .AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Customer)
                .Select(x => new ReservationVM {
                    Customer = x.Key,
                    Reservations = x.ToList(),
                    VesselReservations = GetCustomerVessels(x.ToList()),
                    Total = x.Select(r => r.TotalPersons).Sum()
                })
                .OrderBy(x => x.Customer);
   return result;
}

public List<VesselReservationVM>  GetCustomerVessels( 
  List<Reservation> reservations) {
   var result = reservations
           .GroupBy(r => r.Vessel)
           .Select(g => new VesselReservationVM
           {
              Vessel = g.Key,
              Passengers = g.Select(r => r.TotalPersons).Sum(),
           })
           .ToList();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: @ OfirD Thanks for posting an answer. From what I can figure out, you have implemented TWO methods that seem to have been called (somehow) seperately. However, the specifications dictate that only ONE object should be returned (One VM instance for each customer). So, unless method A calls method B (which returns the result to the caller - method A), its of no use.

Comment: Well, we can simply add a `List<VesselReservationVM>` property to  `ReservationVM`, and  fill it - see editted code.

Comment: @ OfirD I'll give it a go in the next 24 hours and will let you know. Thanks a million!

Comment: @ OfirD I have no words to describe my gratitude. I did all the modifications, did the mappings and now I have a working piece of code according to the specs. Of course, in retrospect and with the solution in front of my eyes, I wonder what the fuss was all about! Have an absolutely fantastic day.